# SQL unique data in range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample table like this:

| Code | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 9:30:06 |
| A | 9:30:07 |
| A | 10:00:00 |
| B | 10:30:00 |
| A | 10:45:00 |
| B | 10:46:01 |
| B | 10:46:00 |

I want:

| Code | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 9:30:06 |
| A | 10:00:00 |
| B | 10:30:00 |
| A | 10:45:00 |
| B | 10:46:01 |

The time selected is not important, the `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT ON` should be on a range of 1 second.

EDIT: All `code` within 1 second of each other are considered duplicate and only one row of them should be selected.

Comment: Now it looks good! Okay, I am really confused. What is the primary difference between these tables? What's the goal? Right now, it is really lacking information.

Comment: I don't understand this problem. How come all of 10:00:00 and A is in th eoutput if A was already set at 9:30:06

Comment: Have edited the question to explain the problem.

Comment: left join to self on your I code and A.Time < B.Time  and A interval+1 <=B.  Then  include in the where clause only records where B.ID is null

Comment: What if there are 10 rows with times 10:00:01, 10:00:02, 10:00:03, ..., 10:00:10 which differ by 1 sec. Do you want to keep only 1 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table called `codes` which has two columns (`code` and `time`), the following query will produce the exact result you're looking for (as per above tables):

```
WITH dup_codes AS (
  SELECT code, time FROM codes c1
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  1 from codes c2
              WHERE c2.code = c1.code
              -- this is where magic happens!
              AND c2.time + interval '1 second' = c1.time
             )
)

SELECT * FROM Codes
WHERE time NOT IN (SELECT time FROM dup_codes);
```

Db Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c9c4def09b06f04f77d5fa71f29e6c57

Comment: Elegent and Simple